# limit set of a bounded solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Going over my lecture notes I have noticed that my professor uses poincare bendixson theorem whenever we have a solution x(t) that remain bounded for all time, but shouldn't we also know that the limit set for for x(t) is non empty to use poincare bendixson theorem?
Or does the following proposition hols?

Lets consider a solution x(t) of a planar differential equation and assume that x(t) remains bounded for all time then the limit set of x(t) is non empty
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, for any sequence $t_n\to\infty$ the sequence $x(t_n)$ contains a convergent subsequence; its limit belongs to the limit set of $x$.

Comment: cheers, good to finally clarify that